# How can I get BF4 Premium?

Tags: battlefield-4

I recently learned that the Premium subscription gives me free DLC. How can I get this?  Preferably without paying too much for it.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade!  Unfortunately, you seem to have been downvoted rather heavily on this question.  This is due to lack of effort on your part.  We don't mind helping you with your gaming problems, but we do expect you to attempt to help yourself first.

Comment: As per Frank... VERY FIRST google result: https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=BF4+Premium+subscription

Answer (score 1):

For a start, premium isn't "free dlc" it's a service that gives you all the dlc maps as it's basically the season pass, it just has other perks too like priority access to servers, battlepacks, exp events etc.
Now I got all my bf4 stuff from here, it's perfectly legit and legal, you're just buying a key.
http://www.cdkeys.com/pc/games/battlefield-4-premium-service-pc-cd-key-origin?gclid=CKj21ub74r4CFZQZtAodCnEANA
it's £25.90 + 5% discount when you get the code for liking their facebook page :) see you on the battlefield.